# Stopping 3D object in place

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am at 1.2 stage (moving the player) at Unity course ["Roll-a-ball"](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) and have question:

I want to add feature that stops a player and sets his new position on 0, 0, 0.

I can reset the position, but I have really problem with stopping a player. The ball won't stop rolling.

My code is:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

        private Rigidbody rb;
        public float speed = 1.0f;

        void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

            Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

            rb.AddForce(movement*speed);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                rb.position = new Vector3(0,0.5f,0);
            }
            print(movement);
        }
    }
```

What I tried?

- Adding new vector3 (0,0,0) in `if` section,
- New vector3 that is opposite to movement,
- `.Stop` after ascribing new position to (0,0,0), but it 'freezes' before (example: I click space when sphere is at board's edge, then it freezes there, when I click arrow it go to new position and start going).

So, how to do that? I have no clue right now, although problem seems
   be easy.

Here a image with code and Unity with opened Inspector on object.
[image]

**EDIT**

I've a another problem.

Changed code as below (as Byte56 suggested):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    speed = 0;
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rb.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;
    speed = 1.0f;
}
if (moveHorizontal != 0 || moveVertical != 0)
{
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
}
```

It seems like clicing space not always freezes object. It always put it on right place, but sometimes doesn't freeze. No matter if I use code `rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;` or `rb.Sleep();` - sometimes it works, sometimes not. I can't prove it, but it seems the smaller is delta of time between clicking space (smaller than 1 second) the chance that it won't freeze increases. It's not fault of space, I tried it with NumEnter.
Any idea? It seems really buggy.

Comment: I recreated this scene on my own. In about 5 minutes of testing I never encountered a time when pressing space didn't result in the expected result. If you're still having trouble, you should post as a new question, not continuing to edit this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop a physics object from moving, you need to zero the forces and the velocity of the `RigidBody`.

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

For zeroing the force, you can apply a force opposite to the forces you've added that frame already. However, I'd suggest simply not adding those forces if you're stopping. It means a slight rearrangement of your code.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    rb.position = new Vector3(0,0.5f,0);
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
} else {
    rb.AddForce(movement*speed);
}
```

The ultimate way to stop the ball, activating all the constraints on the rigidbody.

```
if(moveHorizontal != 0 || moveVertical != 0) //for starting the movement again
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    rb.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0.5f,0);
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;
} else {
    rb.AddForce(movement*speed);
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38146/discussion-between-byte56-and-szkaplerny).

Answer (score 1):

It is due to constantly applying `AddForce` in `FixedUpdate`. You can easily do it by assigning zero to `speed` and set `velocity` to zero.

```
rb.AddForce(movement*speed);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            speed = 0;
            rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity);
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.position = new Vector3(0,0.5f,0);
        }

// Change speed from zero to any other value when you want to move it again.
```

Comment: As below - it doesn't stop immediately, but slowing and slowing and slowing sphere. The second thing is that setting `speed` to zero means I can't move this sphere again after clicking 'space'.

Comment: on clicking space you can set speed to 1.0f again

Comment: nah, I didn't think about it, of course you are right.
Any idea how to deal with my problem another than `.velocity`?

Comment: I think you are setting velocity or adding force anywhere else in your code

Comment: That's my whole code, there is link in first line of my post to this course, I'm doing everything as in video. Now I look at my Inspector and there aren't any values matching this problem. If you want I can put here photo of Unity panels.

Comment: Well, I really could not pick your problem, but you can give a try by putting this code in my answer's space's if check. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I put it into my code but it didn't help.